# How do I transfer an IntelliJ Ultimate license and configuration from one system to another?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a new computer, and I'd like to transfer my IntelliJ Ultimate license from the old system to the new one, and also bring over my configuration.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA license is not tied to a physical machine, rather to a user / account. Therefore, there is no need to transfer your license; you just [register the IDE as usual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/register.html) on a new system.

As for the settings, you can use the [import/export](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#import-export-settings) or the settings sync feature.

Another way would be to just copy the [configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory) from one machine to another.

Comment: Maybe a bit more detail is needed regarding the first paragraph... you register the new one, but if you have only one license, what happens to the old one? I'd like to temporarily keep both IDE's running, while I move to my new PC; then I would uninstall from the old one. Would this be possible, do you know?

Comment: @pgr See https://sales.jetbrains.com/hc/en-gb/articles/207240675-Can-several-products-be-used-at-the-same-time-with-the-All-Products-license-.